# Comparing two columns case-sensitive in Excel

Tags: excel

I want to compare two columns in Excel with the command A3 = B3 to verify if they are true or false.

The issue is that this functionality is not case-sensitive. For example, if I have the following columns to compare:

[image]

I want this to be false, not true. Do you know if it is possible to change it to case-sensitive?

Thanks!

Comment: use EXACT(): `=EXACT(A3,B3)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just used a function named: EXACT, it is case sensitive.
if A1= "Paid Search", B1="paid search", type in C1

> =EXACT(A1;B1)

it will return FALSE in Your case because this function is case-sensitive.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! :)